# Unit testing if condition

Tags: angular, unit-testing, if-statement, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

0

I am writing unit tests and I am a bit stuck on this method. I have onClickCheck method that takes name from formGroup (this part I cover in the test) and then checks if the data.action equals NEW and if name exists and then does something.

onClickCheck() {
const name = this.formGroup.get('name').value;

```
if (this.data.action === 'NEW' && name) {
    this.service
        .doSomething(name)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe((result: any) => {
            this.someVar = result.data.attributes;

            if (this.someVar.isDeleted) {
                this.confirmationDialog(dialogData);
            }
        });
}
```

}
In my test I tried to do it like this but I get Error: expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled() but the number of calls is 0.

const doSomethingSpy = spyOn(
service,
'doSomething'
).and.callThrough();

```
    component.formGroup.setValue({
        name: 'Test',
        lastName: 'TT2'
    });

    component.data= {
        action: 'NEW',
        item: null
    };

    const name = component.formGroup.get('name').value;

    component.onClickCheck();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(doSomethingSpy ).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

How can I test the code inside this double condition IF?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is:

```
const doSomethingSpy = spyOn(service, 'doSomething').and.callThrough();
```

It seems like this observable is never emitting even though we are calling through.

Try changing the line to:

```
spyOn(service, 'doSomething').and.returnValue(of({ data: { attributes: { isDeleted: true } } }); // return whatever you want
```

That should hopefully fix it for you or get you further.